# two cases one field mysql concatenate

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have this code:

```
SELECT * , CASE 
     WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(random.product_name) > 32 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(random.product_name, 1, 32), '...') ELSE random.product_name
   END AS product_name, `brand_name`, CASE 
     WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(random.brand_name) > 18 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(random.brand_name, 1, 18), '...')
     ELSE random.brand_name
   END AS brand_name
```

I need to use the product_name twice, once where it is concatenated when larger than 32 characters, then I need this again without concatenating it - can I add a new case to this to get the full product_name?

Comment: it is not very clear you mean like this: `SELECT random.product_name, 
   CASE 
     WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(random.product_name) > 32 
     THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(random.product_name, 1, 32), ....`

Comment: I mean I have the variable for product_name which is 32 chars, but I also need the full product_name not limited to 32 chars

Comment: Actually you shouldn't be doing that in query but in application.

Comment: can this be done with php?

Comment: got it $string = substr($string,0,10).'...';